Is it possible to duplicate a bytes_stream from reqwest in Rust
I am looking to make a get request to a URL and get the response as a bytes_stream from here I want to make 2 put requests with this data.
Is there a way to make the get request once and somehow duplicate the bytes_stream that is returned.
let response = client.get(get_url).send().await.unwrap();
let stream = response.bytes_stream();
let body = Body::wrap_stream(stream);
// Duplicate the body somehow?

// I will run these concurrently at some stage.
client.put(upload_url_1)
    .body(body)
    .send().await.unwrap()
    .text().await.unwrap();

client.put(upload_url_2)
    .body(duplicated_body)
    .send().await.unwrap()
    .text().await.unwrap();


Just collect the bytes from the response and pass a clone to each concurrent process. You can't clone a Body or a Stream apparently.

Collect into Bytes and clone it (it is a very cheap operation).

It's possible but not good, you could have a struct that implement Stream that take an inner Stream then you would need to store the data in the stream to be able to feed the data multiple time, and finally you would need to find a way to have a cursor for each Stream... say otherwise, it's no longer a Stream but a bad implemented Vector.
If you need to read a data twice you need to store it, in your case a Vec<u8> will work perfectly fine (or use Bytes). If you need to share it Arc<[u8]> or just clone the Vector.

Bytes is even better than both, and also cheaply cloneable.

This will only be better in the very unlikely case that both streams are advanced concurrently, at the same time. That is, after you call a.next(), before you call a.next() again, you call b.next(), or at most there is a lag of only few items. The duplicating stream will have two maintain all bytes read by a but not b (or the opposite) in memory, so if the lag is big you lose the advantage and this will consume the same amount of memory and be much less efficient than just collecting all bytes.

@ChayimFriedman oh yes indeed you only need to keep the data if there would be one Stream waiting for it, that actually interesting now, thus that look like a lot of pain haha, I think I will still let the simple advice to collect.
